# Qt Creator (4.5 beta) - can't make connection to gdbserver

Tags: gdb, qt-creator, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I've been setting up remote debugging for an embedded Linux target.  I've tested that I have the correct combination of gdbserver running on the target and gdb client running on my workstation.  I can start the server and on the workstation side run:

(gdb) target remote 10.28.22.226:2345

and I can list source and step just fine.

In Qt Creator I have configured a device.  In that window I specify the GDB server executable: gdbserver (see pic).

[image: Devices setup]

I also configure the cross debugger in the 'Build & Run' Debuggers tab as shown below:

[image: Build & Run Debuggers setup]

In this case, I have manually started the gdbserver with my executable on the target with port 2345.  To start debugging with Qt Creator, I choose the Debug->Start Debugging->Attach to running Debug server pulldown menu.  It gives me the prompt shown below, where I enter the server port (2345).  I give it the appropriate kit and local executable (copy of the executable on the remote target).

[image: Start Debugger dialog]

After I hit OK, it seems to run the gdb client locally with a few commands, then times out trying to communicate with the gdbserver.  I have debug logging turned on with the server, so I know the server never sees anything from the client run from Qt Creator.  Additionally, I did Window->Views->Debugger Log to help me get a better idea of what was going on.  The log shows the correct IP address and port for my device, but I don't see anything that looks like a 'target remote IP:port' call.

I'm looking for a hint or reference here.  I seem to be a bit stuck at the moment.  Thanks!

EDIT: additional information - I've verified that my gdb client has support for python compiled in.  I see that Qt Creator requires python support.  I also have further support that nothing ever goes out on the wire from Qt Creator.  I did a wireshark capture and don't see anything going to port 2345 on the target.

Alternately, if anyone would share their Qt Creator debugger-log output with me so I can compare, that would be helpful.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the 4.5 beta.  I ran a copy of Qt Creator 4.3.1 and I got it to work.  In 4.3.1, the dialog that comes up with Debug->Start Debugging->Attach to running debug server has a field to 'override server address'.  When I added my IP address there it just worked (without overriding the server address it tried to go to the ssh port for some reason).  I saw 'target remote tcp:10.28.22.226:2345' in the QtC debugger-log.

Comment: I created QTCREATORBUG-19392 at bugreports.qt.io.

Comment: Tried Qt Creator 4.5RC1 and didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid Qt Creator 4.5-beta1.  It seems 4.5RC1 doesn't have this problem.  I was able to do remote debugging using the method described above just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even QtCreator 4.5.0 seems to have the same bug.
The only workaround I've found is to start the GDB server manually on the remote target: with "top" I get the pid of the remote process to debug then I run the following command: **gdbserver --attach remote ip:remote port pid**.
After the server is listening, I finally choose: "Attach to Running Debug" server".

Maybe you can write a server start script on target which include the above statement...

Comment: Saw your comment on the qt-creator bug site.  I have not been using the Debug menu, but rather the Play and Debug icons in the lower left of the QtC screen.  Those work for me when the deploy information is properly set up.  If 'Play' is chosen it copies target file(s) over and runs.  If 'Debug', it also remotely starts the gdb server.

Can I assume you've set up a client cross debugger and associated that with your kit?  Also, is the gdb server on your target in the path and named 'gdbserver'?  Make sure Devices settings have correct ssh port and if necessary a range for Free ports.

Comment: Maybe I have not been able to make me understood: when I need to debug an  application on a remote device it's OK: both from the Debug Menu and the icon on the button of screen. My problem is debugging a child process i.e. a process which is created by the application. I need to break inside this process not the main application and in the previous releases of QTCreator, attacching to a child process was working. In v.4,5 something is broken.If it may help I could be more precise about my application Maybe some other could be interested..

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying.  I didn't get that information from your first comment.  I have not tried to do what you are doing - good luck!